# One to one unidirectional add a unique constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2, spring-data-jpa with hibernate

I have a one to one unidirectional relation

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "samplings_id_seq", strategy = "com.lcm.model.SamplingSequenceGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "samplings_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Products product;
    ...
}   


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Products extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "products_id_seq", sequenceName = "products_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "products_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    ...
}
```

Why hibernate create me this constraint?

```
alter table if exists lcm.samplings 
   add constraint UK_oofms38wiq2q4v0w40a2qdk6f unique (product_id);
```

I must be able to do this scenario

Sampling x with product y
Sampling z with product y

Actually with constraint hibernate added, I can't, I do not understand?

Comment: Because it's a **One**ToOne. If you need several samplings referencing the same product, it should be a **Many**ToOne.

Comment: Also, BTW, the class used to represent a String is called String, not Strings, because one instance of this object is one String. Why do you name your classes Products and Samplings, instead of Product and Sampling?

Comment: you can find a ton of debate about plurar vs singular for the table name on the web. I decided to use same name for object and table... use anotation to change table name with plurar and use singular for the class name...

Comment: It isn't about a table name. it's about a class name. The class that you'll use everywhere in your code and that will make it hard to read. But hey, it's your mess...

Comment: it's  a "s" make it harder to read... maybe you need to change your glass, seriously